# How can I let user rearrange Jbuttons or Jtexfields with drag and drop?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, jbutton, jtextfield

I've made an equation builder program. it displays the terms with textboxes and buttons in a single line. each control is a term 3 * 3 is 2 textboxes for the numbers and a button for the *. I would like drag and drop to be implemented for changing the order of these. I'm just missing on crucial part I need to know how to detect where the control is dropped, either on the jpanel they are in or if dropped on a jbutton which physical part of the jbutton. Basically I just need to know whether to put it on the left or the right.

I currently have it kind of working where when you start to drag I make little catcher buttons appear in between each control but honestly it looks like crap and doesn't work that well.

Comment: I don't believe there is anyway to do this without the use of a custom layout. If the drag-and-drop objects don't have to be components, consider making graphics objects and moving those.

Comment: the layout I'm using is Miglayout if that changes anything. unfortunately it requires components at this stage. It's tied into a lot of other code.

Comment: When dragging just get the mouse down and mouse dragged/released co-ords (relative to the parent container), then add/subtract that from the textbox position (relative to the same parent container) and you can easily work out if it should be on the left of right. If you want it to be visually interactive then you can render a snapshot of the textbox and draw that to a graphics plane on top of everything else (just while it is dragging), based on the location of the current dragged mouse location, then when the mouse is released it will snap to left or right based on the co-ords.

Comment: Perhaps @camickr's [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) class may help you out here or at the very least point you into a direction you would like to go. It helped me in one of my projects.

Comment: You'd create a `JButton` subtype that implements `Transferable`, create a `DataFlavor` for that subtype, handle the exporting/importing of buttons via a `TransferHandler` that you attach to the container (IE: `JPanel` - whatever container mediates the movement), then finally you'd attach a `MouseListener` to the container to generate a drag event. Check out [Intro to DnD](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html). Not the simplest of tasks, but definitely possible.

Comment: sorry it took so long to get back to this, had to work on another part for a while. I already know about that stuff Vince, I need to know how to detect specific information. I'll look more into Sorifiend's suggestion of coordinate based and post followup questions if I have issues with that. thank you everyone.